# Grails 2.1.x dependency problems

Tags: grails, dependency-management

I encountered the following error messages while setting up my out-of-box grails application:

> Server access Error: Connection refused: connect url=http://grails.org/plugins/grails-antlr/tags/RELEASE_2_7_6/antlr-2.7.6.pom
>   ...

There were multiply JIRA issues around the issue which suggested to change the version of `antlr` used by Hibernate, but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a problem with Grails proxy settings. To configure it properly on Windows machine use following commands:

```
grails add-proxy proxyname "--host=proxy.example.com" "--port=8080"
grails set-proxy proxyname
```

There're two things to pay attention: set the proxy with a `set-proxy` command after it was added and use double quotes when executing from Windows command line.